# Cypress + Cucumber doesn't work with regex

Tags: javascript, cucumber, cypress

I have the following step definition in my cypress-cucumber project:

```
Given('I open home page', () => {
    cy.visit('/', {
        failOnStatusCode: false,
        headers: {
            'Accept-Language': 'en',
        },
    })
})
```

It works fine as soon as I use it with the line:

```
Given I open home page
```

But I want this step definition to work not only with this line but also with this one:

```
Given user opens home page
```

And when I change my step definition like this:

```
'(.+) open(s?) home page'
```

It doesn't work anymore. Cypress writes that my step is not defined. Why? How to fix this regex?

Comment: Do you know which version of cucumber-js you're using? A fairly long time ago we switched to https://cucumber.io/docs/cucumber/cucumber-expressions/ which is a simplified pattern language - maybe that's the problem?

Comment: Also, you may want to try asking for help on the community Slack channel: https://cucumberbdd.slack.com/archives/C6QJ6N695

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I found the reason already. The problem was that I was using single quotes instead of slashes. I'm new to javascript, previously I only worked with Java, so I didn't know that I had to use slashes in step definitions.